# Why is the ionization energy of radium higher than barium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-table

The ionization energy of radium is higher than barium. The reason provided is that occurs fue to lanthanide contraction. But, Radium isnt a member of lanthanide series. How come we say that lanthanide contraction occurs in it?